# HDFS CopyToLocal function in C#

Tags: c#, hadoop

Copying files from `hdfs` to local machine and I use following code but it shows copy to local did not succeed. And get following exception

```
Exception:
    Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce.StreamingException occurred
      HResult=-2146233088
      Message=Copy to local did not succeed.
      Source=Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce 
Code:    
    HdfsFile.CopyToLocal(hdfspath,localpath)
```

I'd appreciate hel pon this.

Comment: As always, error is on line 57.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itsel**f. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].